# $_ENV vars not set in Laravel Event Listener?

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, bug-reporting

- Laravel Version: 8.54.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.14
- Database Driver & Version: Mysql / 8.0.23

#### The Problem

A composer package my app requires uses $_ENV to access env vars. I'm using a class from this package in a listener that is registered in `EventServiceProvider` in the `$listen` property. The $_ENV values are not set. The $_ENV variables are correctly loaded from .env everywhere else. This package is not Laravel specific, so `env()` helper is not an option.

[This issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6647), which is closed, mentions the same issue but, I thought `getenv` is discouraged and should be avoided being it is not thread safe.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

- Register a listener in EventServiceProvider@$listen

```php
// EventServiceProvider.php
protected $listen = [
        \App\Events\FooEvent::class    => [
            \App\Listeners\FooListener::class,
        ],
];
```

- In FooListener::class, call $_ENV['FOO'];

Comment: have you tried using the env helper function by laravel itself, `env('FOO', false)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but laravel helpers are only helpful for laravel specific code/packages. I am developing a php package (non laravel specific), so the env helper function is not available. What it ultimately boils down to is the way Laravel loads variables from .env causes those variables to not be available in some areas of Laravel. In my case, and others, it is in event listeners.